# Ubuntu 17.04 Software & Updater Failed to download repository information

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, repository

I got the following error messages when I try to re-load software & updates:

```
E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I tried solution at [Xenial repository does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/xenial-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file) but it does not work for me.

Comment: Your links solves the issue but you must understand what the problem is and adapt the solutions to your specific issue. I see no effort here, unfortunately. PS - 17.04 is about to be EoL, I advise you to upgrade to 17.10 ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

You get that error when the line is incorrectly typed or the server does not answer in an expected way. In your case, I'm almost sure you typed the address incorrectly.

Look in /etc/apt and inspect either the big sources.list or files in sources.list.d.  Note these have a SLASH after "ubuntu/". All of mine do, eg:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful restricted multiverse main universe
```

Also, be aware that ppa servers come and go rapidly.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for help. I added SLASH in both sources.list and files that start with mc3man or shutter in sources.list.d but still no luck. I even tried to download a newly generated sources.list. Is there any way I can block these 2 items? thanks

Comment: You need to show us exactly what is in the list file you are using. Put it as a separate file under /etc/apt/sources.list.d. Put it in as I did mine, which does work.  Note after the name of the repo and the Ubuntu version, I have keywords like "main" or "multiverse".  You must have something wrong there. You'd not have the word "Release", for example.